# Transferring specific cell data from sheet to sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a problem where I need to transfer the cell data from one sheet to another. What I'm trying to achieve in the end is that if I click a button, it will import my data from the sheet one sheet to the sheet I'm currently using.

My original code looked like this:

```js
function C2() {
  var sourceSheet  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("C2");

var destSheet  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  sourceSheet.getRange("A1:I43").copyTo(destSheet.getRange("A1:I43"), {contentsOnly:true});
}
```

But that won't work for the new modifications I've made. It's erasing the formulas in the cells on the next sheet and replacing them with the values of the previous sheet that the formulas produced.

I've tried to use this formula, selecting all of the areas that I'd like to transfer, but it results in a "range not found" error message.

```js
function C1() {
  var sourceSheet  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("C1");

var destSheet  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  sourceSheet.getRange("A2,A4:B16,A21,A23,A25,A27,D3:D22,E4:E22,F3:H22,C24,C26:E31,F25,L1").copyTo(destSheet.getRange("A2,A4:B16,A21,A23,A25,A27,D3:D22,E4:E22,F3:H22,C24,C26:E31,F25,L1"), {contentsOnly:true});
}
```

If it's possible to cherry pick the cells I need and transfer them to my desired sheet instead of only using a broad range (ex. "A1:I43"), That would be ideal. Any and all help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### You need to define a [RangeList](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range-list) and iterate through all the contained ranges.

If you want to copy values only, [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) and [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) will be useful methods for you:

```
function myFunction() {
  var spreadsheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("C2");
  var destSheet  = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var rangeList=sourceSheet.getRangeList(["A2","A4:B16","A21","A23","A25","A27","D3:D22","E4:E22","F3:H22","C24","C26:E31","F25","L1"]);
  var rangeList2=destSheet.getRangeList(["A2","A4:B16","A21","A23","A25","A27","D3:D22","E4:E22","F3:H22","C24","C26:E31","F25","L1"]); 
  for (var i=0;i<rangeList.getRanges().length;i++){
       rangeList2.getRanges()[i].setValues(rangeList.getRanges()[i].getValues());
  }
}
```

Comment: This is great, but if it's possible, could the script import the data into the current sheet that's being viewed. For example, I have a button for the script on each of the 30 sheets. If I'm on sheet 10 and I want to import sheet 20, I would press the button marked "20." Is this sort of thing possible?

Comment: Sure. Just replace `getSheetByName("Sheet1")` through `getActiveSheet()`.